# Adding Google Analytics event tracking to Javascript alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

So I have a basic function

```
<script>
window.onbeforeunload=function() 
{ 
return 'Please save'
}
</script>
```

And i'm aware of how to put events in for use with Google analytics, but I can't figure out exactly where the tracking code needs to be without breaking the function.

```
<script>
window.onbeforeunload=function() 
{ 
onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'alert', 'clicked');"
return 'Please save'
}
</script>
```

This is what I have tried, but i'm not sure onClick is correct but I am unsure of what the next step is to figure out how to correctly track them clicking "leave" or "stay"

Thanks in advance

Comment: Remove the onclick and the quotes. You'd use the onclick event handler only when a user clicks an element. In this case there is no clicked element. It is enough to use the ga function call (onbeforeunload already is an event handler). If you are trying to track the click on the button of the alert box, that is simply not possible (but then users have to click anyway before they are able to do anything in that tab).

Comment: @EikePierstorff
That works, thank you very much